# Javascript error: unable to get value, even though it is not null

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a bit of javascript code that gets and sets the scroll position based on a hidden input field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="scroll" runat="server" value="0" />

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function setScroll() {
        document.getElementById('scroll').value = document.getElementById("scrollDiv").scrollTop;
    }

    function scrollToPos {
        document.getElementById("scrollDiv").scrollTop = document.getElementById("scroll").value;
    }
```

And for some reason it says the value of the hidden input field is always undefined. Does anyone have any explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have got runat="server" in there it is probably changing the ID when its generated.

Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var scrollId = "<%= scroll.ClientID %>";

    function setScroll() {
        document.getElementById(scrollId).value = document.getElementById("scrollDiv").scrollTop;
    }

    function scrollToPos {
        document.getElementById("scrollDiv").scrollTop = document.getElementById(scrollId).value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Great tip - probably a fairly easy thing to overlook. Thanks for the help :)